# How to push docker image from jenkins to GCP artifact repo

Tags: maven, jenkins, google-artifact-registry, maven-jib

I wanted to push the docker image from Jenkins(Running on same GCP project) to GCP Artifact Repo. I am using the maven-jib plugin to build and push the image. Maven-jib-plugin supports the container registry(It's Deprecated) but no documentation for the artifact registry.

Could you please help me with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jenkins community](https://community.jenkins.io/t/push-to-google-artifact-registry-through-jenkins-pipeline/7868):

- Create a service account for Artifact Registry and grant it [Artifact Registry Writer IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles) (`roles/artifactregistry.writer`).
- [Create a service account JSON key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#creating).
- Upload the JSON key into Jenkins Manage Credentials as Secret File and use it as a credential to connect to Artifact Registry.

Here's an example of jenkinsfile to push to Artifact Registry:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    PROJECT = "you-gcp-project"
    APP_NAME = "you-app-name"
    REPO_NAME = "your-repo-name"
    REPO_LOCATION = "your-repo-location"
    IMAGE_NAME = "${REPO_LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO_NAME}/${APP_NAME}"
  }

  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: test
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: docker
            image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
              name: docker-sock
          - name: kubectl
            image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          volumes:
          - name: docker-sock
            hostPath:
              path: /var/run/docker.sock
      '''
    }
  }
  
  stages {
    stage('Pull Git'){
      when { expression { true } }
      steps{
        checkout scm
      }
    }

    stage('Build docker image') {
    when { expression { true } }
      steps{
        container('docker'){
          dir('Backend Net/MyDotnet') {
            echo 'Build docker image Start'
            sh 'pwd'
            sh 'docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} .'
            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${PROJECT}_artifacts", variable: 'GCR_CRED')]){
              sh 'cat "${GCR_CRED}" | docker login -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin https://"${REPO_LOCATION}"-docker.pkg.dev'
              sh 'docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}'
              sh 'docker logout https://"${REPO_LOCATION}"-docker.pkg.dev'
            }
            sh 'docker rmi ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}'
            echo 'Build docker image Finish'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may refer to the documentations below for your reference:

- [Set up authentication for Docker](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication)
- [Integrating with Jenkins](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-jenkins)

Comment: Thanks, @Robert G  for the response. But I wanted to use the maven-jib-plugin for building and pushing images as it skip the requirement to install docker on Jenkins and no need to create a docker file also.

Comment: @Gourav, based on this [changelog](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-gradle-plugin/CHANGELOG.md#310), jib now tries [Google ADC](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials), similar with `gcr.io`.

Comment: You may also check this documentation on [building Java containers with Jib](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/jib). Hope this helps.